# jQuery can't get .closest() to search up DOM tree

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/3Bvt9/3/

HTML

```
<div id="div1">
    <img class="size" src="">
    <input name="rdo" id="rdo" type="radio" value="1">
    <div id="div2">
        <label>radiobutton</label>
        <div id="div3">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">link</a>
            <input name="abc" id="abc" type="hidden" value="1">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$('#abc').parent().parent().parent().find("input[type='radio']").length; //1
$('#abc').closest("input[type='radio']").length; //0 why?
```

Why doesn't the closest query work? I thought closest() traverses up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

Comment: _I thought closest() traverses up through its ancestors in the DOM tree._ Yes, but an input can't be a parent element.

Comment: The documentation says "For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree." Wouldn't that selector match the first found radio input? Which are valid parents? Can .closest() only find those types?

Comment: What's up with the close votes btw? It's a real question "why doesn't it work" with an obvious answer.

Comment: Indent the HTML correctly, and all will become instantly clear.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is because `input[type="radio"]` is not a parent of `#abc`, rather it's a sibling of the grandparent element.

Also, [according to w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4), `<input>` elements can't have child elements, unlike `<button>`, i.e. it doesn't "wrap" around `#abc`.

The first method works because `$('#abc').parent().parent().parent()` points to the top `<div>`; doing `.find("input[type='radio']")` on that will find the radio button as its child element.

This would also work:

```
$('#abc').parent().parent().siblings('input[type="radio"]).length; // 1
```

Comment: If I only had the id of #abc, What method can I use to find the closest radio button going up the DOM? Is there a better way than using several .parent() methods?

Comment: @duyn9uyen You could give the grandparent element a classname I suppose, but there will always be the somewhat awkward "find sibling of grandparent" code.

Comment: Will .closest() only find direct parents? So in this case, it will only find the three divs?

Comment: @duyn9uyen Yeah, that's the definition of ancestors in HTML DOM :)